# How to append text to a text file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I would like to be able to append text at the end of an existing file. This means the file should not be overwritten when the new text is added to it.

This is how I would do that in plain C++:

```
ofstream fout("filename.txt", ios::app)
```

Here is how I am trying to do that using Qt, but it is not working:

```
void addToDatabase::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    QString make = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QString model = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
    QString price = ui->lineEdit_3->text();
    QString miles = ui->lineEdit_4->text();

    QFile myDatabase(myDatabasePath);
    if (myDatabase.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Append)) {
        QTextStream out(&myDatabase);
        out << make << "    " << model << "    " << price << "    " << miles << endl;
        myDatabase.flush();
        myDatabase.close();
    }
    this->close();
}
```

I've noticed that when I try to read my *QFile* it doesn't work either. I think this is because the declaration of *myDatabase* on line 7 is overwriting the old *database.txt* file at the given path.

Comment: The code you've provided works for me. Show a debug message in an _else_ statement after `if (myDatabase...` in order to be sure that the file is indeed being opened.

Comment: Works for me too now I duplicated the code by accident further up in my class without the append parameter. So derp... three hours wasted.

Comment: That is why a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is required. Many times this alone solves the problem and eliminates the need to post anything.

Comment: Also, check those return values of IO functions... Many "bugs" (even if not this one) are simply bad permissions,wrong paths, ....

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated the code by accident before this function without using the append parameter. So basically the file was deleting itself every time and then calling this new function where I wanted to append to the now wiped file.